# Trouble ordering GROUP BY, ORDER BY AND JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join

i'm having trouble ordering a query.

I have this table (AttendanceLog);

```
ClassID | StudentPin | Status


   69           1        YES
   8            2        NO
   10           2        NO
   17           3        NO
   43           5        YES
   58           6        YES
```

and this table (Students):

```
STUDENTPIN | FNAME | LNAME | INTERNATIONAL 
     1         X       X         NO
     2         X       X         YES
     3         X       X         NO
     4         X       X         YES
```

I want to find out the which INTERNATIONAL students (Fname, Lname and StudentPIN) have missed 10 or more classes (attendancelog status being no).

Currently I have this (below) which tells me the studentPIN and the number of classes attended and no attended by each student, however I am unable to join the two tables together.

```
SELECT
    ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_yes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_no
FROM attendancelog
GROUP BY ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin
ORDER BY ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a join

```
SELECT
    ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin,
    Students.FNAME,
    Students.LNAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_yes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_no
FROM attendancelog
INNER JOIN Students ON Students.STUDENTPIN = attendancelog.StudentPin 
                         and INTERNATIONAL='YES' 
GROUP BY ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin, Students.FNAME, Students.LNAME
ORDER BY ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin
```

Comment: This works for selecting only international students but when I add the selection for first name and last name and error appears

Answer (score 0):

Join on `student pin`, put your `international = 'YES'` filter in the `where` clause, and filter for more than 10 misses in a `having` clause. You can also shorten the `case` expressions a little:

```
select a.studentpin
     , s.fname, s.lname, s.international
     , count(case a.status when 'YES' then 1 end) as attended
     , count(case a.status when 'NO'  then 1 end) as missed
from   attendancelog a
       join students s on s.studentpin = a.studentpin
where  international = 'YES' 
group  by s.fname, s.lname, s.international, a.studentpin
having count(case a.status when 'NO'  then 1 end) > 10
order  by s.fname, s.lname, a.studentpin;
```